# New Android Fragment or Activity

Tags: android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, detailsview

I have MainActivity which extends FragmentActivity that holds 6 tabs (listfragments) whose items are clickable and after clicking it, the user will get details screen about clicked item from list selected on it's tab(passing argument to newInstance or bundle).

Should i start new activity with fragment inside or it is better to replace R.id.pager just with a fragment avoiding creating new activity for details view of clicked item in list ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depending on your app's navigation style, if a new context is presented when an item is clicked, then a new activity is more appropriate.

If the new view has little detail, then user doesnt need to move in "deeper" in navigation stack, so fragment would be appropriate.

Ideally you want to keep your user close to the root of your navigation but not at the expense of smooth manoeuvring around your app.